How to calculate the limit of this riemann sum using integrals?
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{3}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sqrt{\frac{n}{n+3(k-1)}}
$$
Assuming this can be written as a Riemann Sum, how can I bring it to an integral?
I'm trying to make it reach the form $\operatorname{f}\left(3k/n\right)$ so it's $k$. $\Delta x$ if $\Delta x = 3/n$ but I cannot go any further than this line:
$$
\sqrt{\frac{1}{1 + 3k/n - 3/n}}
$$
I don't know how to get rid of the extra $\Delta x$ or $3/n$.

Hint: use the Riemann sum https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20Riemann%20sum,integral%20by%20a%20finite%20sum.

The $k = 1$-term  already yields $3$. The remaining starts at $k = 2$ which can be shifted to $1$ which removes the “offending term”. Next, $\it Riemann\ldots$ as usual.

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{3}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sqrt{\frac{n}{n+3(k-1)}}= \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{3}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sqrt{\frac{1}{1+(k-1)\cdot \frac3n}}.$$
The sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{3}{n}\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+(k-1)\cdot \frac3n}}$ is a Riemann sum for $f(x)=\sqrt\frac1{1+x}$ on the segment $[0,3]$, split into segments of length $\frac3n$. Indeed, $\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+(k-1)\cdot \frac3n}}$ is the value of $f$ at the beginning of the $k$-th segment. Hence
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{3}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sqrt{\frac{1}{1+(k-1)\cdot \frac3n}}=\int_0^3\frac1{\sqrt{1+x}}~dx=2\sqrt{1+x}\bigg|_0^3=2.$$

Why is it okay to keep it as k-1, shouldn't it only be k?

@Manar Suppose $k=1$, then $(k-1)\cdot\frac3n=0$, so it’s the beginning of the first segment $[0,\frac3n]$. If $k=2$, then $(k-1)\cdot\frac3n=\frac3n$, it’s the beginning of the second segment $[\frac3n,2\cdot\frac3n]$. And so on. This is just a definition of a Riemann sum: a sum of the form (length of the segment)x(some value of $f$ from this segment).

For example, if we choose the partition point as $x=\dfrac{3(k-1)}{n}$,then $\varDelta x=\dfrac{3}{n}$,allowing us to obtain the desired definite integral.

Why is it okay to keep it as k-1, shouldn't it only be k?

That's just a difference in notation. If it feels awkward, you could try substituting $l=k-1$ and reframe it that way.
